Month formula returns the incorrect month from a date
I'm trying to return a month from a date in Google Sheets, but I'm not sure what's happening.
Cell A2 is populated with a date of 12/30/2022. If I select that cell, go to Format > Number, the checked item in the list confirms it's indeed a date formatted as m/dd/yyyy.
Cell B2 has the formula =month(A2), but returns Jan as the month.
What gives?
I've also tried copying A2 into a separate column, converting that into a number (44,925). I've also tried to run the month formula on that, and it also returns the same incorrect month as above.

I think you have Cell B2 formatted as a date (specifically just the month)
=month("12/30/2020") - returns the number 12 which if converted to a date is 1/11/1900 so that formatted as a partial date would return "Jan"
Remove all formatting on B2 and you should get the correct result of 12

The month() function returns a number between 1 and 12. When a cell contains the date 2022-12-30, and a month() formula points to that cell, the value returned is 12.
When you format a cell that contains the value 12 as a date, you get 1900-01-11. If the result cell is formatted as a date, you get a date that shows January. The format MMM will get simply Jan.
To get Dec instead of 12, use text(), like this:
=text(A2; "MMM")

To get a date that corresponds with the first day of the month, and format that date as a month abbreviation, use this pattern:
=query(eomonth(A2; -1) + 1; "format Col1 'MMM' "; 0)

See Working with date and time values in Google Sheets.

=month(A2) output would be 12 & most likely you are converting 12 to the month type which is going to be Jan since number 12 = 11-Jan-1900
try with =text(A2,"mmm")

Use M instead of m to avoid trouble with getting minutes instead of month. See Date & number formats.

mmm seems to be designated to Three letter month abbreviation. Is there any specific input where I can see this distinction?!

@doubleunary I believe thats true only for old LEGACY

mmm will give the month abbreviation, but the point of always using M for months is to avoid eventual trouble. "Use this token to expressly state a month, instead of a minute, in your pattern."

@doubleunary m is going to be taken as a minute if and only the format is explicitly given as h m s OR h m OR m s.  Also just noticed that if preceded by hour, its being taken as a minute irrespective of its m or M ("h m" and "h M")

Yes... the h M thing looks like a bug. But it still makes sense to always use M when you want months. Also see SimpleDateFormat.

your setup is not possible to be reproduced

=month(A2), but returns Jan as the month

MONTH will output only numeric value
only TEXT can output Jan
see green rows how to use formula correctly:

